# Is there any implementation of mtcnn face detection in tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: keras, face-detection, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Recently I've moved to tensorflow==2.0.0-rc0 and now mtcnn for face detection is not working on my computer. Can I find tensorflow==2.0.0-rc0 version of mtcnn? Pure Keras implementation of mtcnn would also work in this situation.

I've tried keras implementation of facenet at https://github.com/nyoki-mtl/keras-facenet. Its nice implementation of facenet in kears but the face detection part (mtcnn in keras) is missing.

Comment: The following repository provides compatibility with tensorflow 2.0 but the core implementation is still in tensorflow 1.https://github.com/ipazc/mtcnn

Comment: A relevant issue: https://github.com/ipazc/mtcnn/issues/56

Comment: Hello @Fisa, did you get any solution? I am also facing the same issue with TF 2.0.

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan The code at the following links is compatible with TF 2.0. However, it can be improved to make it fully TF 2.0 specific. https://pypi.org/project/mtcnn/#description and https://github.com/ipazc/mtcnn

Comment: @Fisa: It throws "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'" error running with TF 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for running MTCNN face_detection in real time:

```
import torch
from torchvision import transforms 
from PIL import Image 
import numpy as np 
import cv2 
from mtcnn import MTCNN

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
detector = MTCNN()


while True:

    ret,frame = cap.read()

    output = detector.detect_faces(frame)

    for single_output in output:
        x,y,w,h = single_output['box']
        cv2.rectangle(frame,pt1=(x,y), pt2=(x+w,y+h),color=(255,0,0),thickness=2)
    cv2.imshow('win',frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ('x'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed TF 2 as well so just pushed up [this library](https://github.com/YaleDHLab/mtcnn). You should be able to clone the repo and `python setup.py install` to install it. It's developed against tensorflow 2.5.0.

P.S. For those looking to port TF 1.x libraries to TF 2 in the future, [this comment](https://github.com/theislab/scgen/issues/14#issuecomment-540553803) may be all you need!

Comment: Retinaface performs better than mtcnn ant its tensorflow version is very easy to use https://github.com/peteryuX/retinaface-tf2